# iOS masterView of UISplitViewController appears on UIButton click

Tags: ios, uibutton, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a splitViewController for my app. My masterView appears when we swipe on the screen and i want to make it appear when we click on a UIButton. I tried but can't make it. My detailView doesn't have a navigationController so I cannot use a navigationBar with a navigation item.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Is that a custom uisplitviewcontroller? Compare it with https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html - in landscape the master is always visible, in portrait it appears when you tap on the button.

Comment: I use the uisplitviewcontroller from Xcode.  My app is in portrait but i don't have a toolbar with a bar button item like Apple's documentation

Comment: You could embed the viewcontroller into a navigationcontroller or tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Oh dammit. I don't need and don't wanna add a navigation bar or tab bar in my view controller. That's why i'm trying to use a UIButton but i think i couldn't make it :(

Comment: Oh, ok. Just add a button to your root viewcontroller's view.

Comment: I added it but how can i make the connection between this button and the master view?